# How to make control variables in corona SDK?

Tags: variables, sdk, coronasdk

I'm trying to make a variable called star1vis( - code for that `star1vis = 0`)
and when collision happens star1vis is 1 ( code - `..... then star1vis = 1` ).
In other Lua file called level1com I'm using that variable which is global
so I can have star visible if collision happened if it haven't been happened then
that star is invisible. I have big experenice with GML(Game Maker Language - similar to C++)
and in that language I was doing it by that so my question is how to create that variable
in lua language because I'm getting nil value error - without that code it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It's the most important thing that, where did you first created star1vis variable?

If you created it in a module, lets say module1.lua, then you can reach it easly with module1.star1vis

But if you created star1vis in main.lua, you may overwrite it in another module. See exapmle below:

main.lua:

```
.....
star1vis = 0 --star1vis first created here
.....
```

module1.lua:

```
.....
star1vis = 1 --you overwrite star1vis here. That means there are 2 star1vis variables with same names in different modules right now. 
-----
-----
print( star1vis ) --if you do this without creating a new variable in module1.lua, this will reach the variable in main.lua.
-----
```

I guess you want to have your variable in main.lua and be able to change it from another modules. If so, here is what you have to do:

main.lua:

```
----
star1vis = 0  --first created
function changestar1vis( new )
    star1vis = new
end
-----
```

module1.lua:

```
------
changestar1vis( 0 )
------
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Sort of u gave me idea how to reach variables from other Luas. Hope it will work! Thanks!

Comment: Nope :sigh: again but now I'm just getting nil values errors from that code you gave me. I put star1vis = 0  --first created
function changestar1vis( new ) 
    star1vis = new
end
in main.lua and changestar1vis( 0 ) in other lua where that value should be used to get star visible

function onLocalCollision( self, event )
 if ( event.other.myName == "flag" ) then 
 storyboard.gotoScene("level1com","fade",200)
 elseif ( event.other.myName == "star1" ) then 
 mchangestar1vis( 1 )
 end
end

Comment: Probably you have a typo or somewhere in the code, you use star1vis = something. did you double checked ?